# Codimension in X, given the codimension in a subspace of X

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space with infinite dimension, let $M$ be a dense subspace of $X$ with codimension $k$ and let $N$ be a dense subspace of $M$ with codimension $l$ in $M$.

The codimension of $N$ in is $k+l$. This follows from the isomorphism theorem which states that $X/M\cong (X/N) / (M/N)$.

Is there another easy way to see this, without using this version of the isomorphism theorem?

Comment: Let $C_M$ be a complement of $M$ in $X$, and $C_N$ a complement of $N$ in $M$. Then $C_M \oplus C_N$ is a complement of $N$ in $X$. Of course it's the same argument in different clothing.